# How to reorder rows in pandas dataframe by factor level in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, ranking

I've created a small dataset comparing coffee drink prices per cup size.

When I pivot my dataset the output automatically reorders the index (the 'Size' column) alphabetically.

Is there a way to assign the different sizes a numerical level (e.g. small = 0, medium = 1, large = 2) and reorder the rows this way instead?

I'm know this can be done in R using the forcats library (using fct_relevel for example), but I'm not aware of how to do this in python. I would prefer to keep the solution to using numpy and pandas.

```py
data = {'Item': np.repeat(['Latte', 'Americano', 'Cappuccino'], 3),
        'Size': ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']*3,
        'Price': [2.25, 2.60, 2.85, 1.95, 2.25, 2.45, 2.65, 2.95, 3.25]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Item', 'Size', 'Price'])
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['Size'], columns = 'Item')
df

#         Price
# Item    Americano Cappuccino  Latte
#   Size            
#  Large       2.45       3.25   2.85
# Medium       2.25       2.95   2.60
#  Small       1.95       2.65   2.25
```

Comment: `df = df.reindex(["Small", "Medium", "Large"])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) type with `ordered=True`:

```
df.index = pd.Categorical(df.index,
                          categories=['Small', 'Medium', 'Large'],
                          ordered=True)
df = df.sort_index()
```

output:

```
           Price                 
Item   Americano Cappuccino Latte
Small       1.95       2.65  2.25
Medium      2.25       2.95  2.60
Large       2.45       3.25  2.85
```

You can access the codes with:

```
>>> df.index.codes
array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int8)
```

If this was a Series:

```
>>> series.cat.codes
```

Comment: Just edited a typo, feel free to re-edit/revert. +1 :)

Comment: As sammy pointed out it's advantageous to convert to categorical before pivoting ;)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create the categorical, before pivoting; for this case I am using `encode_categorical` from `pyjanitor`, primarily for convenience :

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
 .encode_categorical(Size = (None, 'appearance'))
 .pivot_table(index='Size', columns='Item')
)

           Price                 
Item   Americano Cappuccino Latte
Size                             
Small       1.95       2.65  2.25
Medium      2.25       2.95  2.60
Large       2.45       3.25  2.85
```

This way, you do not have to bother about sorting, since pivoting implicitly does that. You can skip the pyjanitor and just stick to Pandas only:

```py
(df
 .astype({'Size': pd.CategoricalDtype(categories = ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large'], 
                                      ordered = True)})
 .pivot_table(index='Size', columns='Item')
)

           Price                 
Item   Americano Cappuccino Latte
Size                             
Small       1.95       2.65  2.25
Medium      2.25       2.95  2.60
Large       2.45       3.25  2.85
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st WAY:**

`pivot_table` function sorts rows based on index.
Thus, It is better to use lambda function when applying index in pivot_table function.
This way, you don't need any further sorting steps(more time consuming) or any third-party library.

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index = (lambda row: 0 if df.loc[row,'Size']=="Small" else 1 if df.loc[row,'Size']=="Medium" else 2), 
                    columns = 'Item')

         Price                 
Item Americano Cappuccino Latte
0         1.95       2.65  2.25
1         2.25       2.95  2.60
2         2.45       3.25  2.85
```

**2nd WAY:**

You can also use your own code and then rename and sort the newly-created table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Item', 'Size', 'Price'])
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['Size'], columns = 'Item')

# rename:
df = df.rename(index= lambda x: 0 if x=="Small" else 1 if x=="Medium" else 2)

#sort:
df = df.sort_index(ascending = True)


         Price                 
Item Americano Cappuccino Latte
0         1.95       2.65  2.25
1         2.25       2.95  2.60
2         2.45       3.25  2.85
```